# ajax load scripts not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, load

hi guy still having problems.. so though re write the question. got my external pages into a div on my index page.. great.. but cant seem to get java scripts to work.. i can get them to work once using this..

```
     <script>
        $.ajax({
        url: "pages/index.php",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(html) {
          var target = $('.fademe');
        var targetHeight = target.outerHeight();
        $(document).scroll(function(e){
            var scrollPercent = (targetHeight - window.scrollY) / targetHeight;
            if(scrollPercent >= 0){
                target.css('opacity', scrollPercent);
            }
        }); 
        }
    });
</script>
```

but when i go to different page and come back it doesnt work... i put my scripts at the bottom of the main index page

```
<script>
    $.ajax({
        url: "pages/index.php",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(html) {
            $('#st-accordion').accordion();
        };
    });

</script>

<script>
       $.ajax({
        url: "pages/index.php",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(html) {
            $('#st-accordion2').accordion();
        }
    });

</script>


<script>
    $(function () {
        $.scrollUp();
    });
</script>

<!-- Fade Top Panel  -->
<script>
        $.ajax({
        url: "pages/index.php",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(html) {
          var target = $('.fademe');
        var targetHeight = target.outerHeight();
        $(document).scroll(function(e){
            var scrollPercent = (targetHeight - window.scrollY) / targetHeight;
            if(scrollPercent >= 0){
                target.css('opacity', scrollPercent);
            }
        }); 
        }
    });
</script>

<script> 

    $ajax({
        url: "pages/index.php"
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(html) {
             $('#submit').click(function(){
            $.post("send.php", $("#mycontactform").serialize(),  function(data) {   });
                 $('#success').html('Message sent!');
                 $('#success').hide(2000);


                    $('#name1').val('');
                    $('#telephone').val('');
                    $('#email').val('');
                    $('#message').val('');

            });
        }


    });




</script>

<!-- Viberating Icons -->


<script>

    $(function() {
        var interval = 10;
        var duration= 1000;
        var shake= 3;
        var selector = $('.viberate'); /* Your own container ID*/
        $(selector).each(function(){
            var elem = this;
            var vibrateIndex;
            var timeoutIndex;
            $(this).hover( /* The button ID */
                function(){ 
                    vibrateIndex = setInterval(function(){
                      vibrate(elem); 
                    }, interval, 0);
                    timeoutIndex = setTimeout(function() 
                   {clearInterval(vibrateIndex)},1000);
                },
                function(){
                clearInterval(vibrateIndex);
                clearTimeout(timeoutIndex); 
                }
            );
        })

            var vibrate = function(elem){
                $(elem).stop(true,false)
                .css({position: 'relative', 
                left: Math.round(Math.random() * shake) - ((shake + 1) / 2) +'px', 
                top: Math.round(Math.random() * shake) - ((shake + 1) / 2) +'px'
            });
                        }
                    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to load JS/CSS at first and then load only information that dynamic.

In this case you will have cached JS/CSS and small response. It means better performance.

And of course **DO NOT** load `<html><head>...</head>` part. Every page has only one `<html>` tag and yours already has one. If you load it you need to strip it. It means you'll do unnecessary work and **ajax will work slower**.

If you using AJAX you need to load only data you need. **Less garbage - faster response**.

**UPDATE**

Try this:

```
<script>



    function init(){

        // Accodion 1 & 2 -->
        $('#st-accordion').accordion();

       $('#st-accordion2').accordion();


        //Scroll Up -->

        $.scrollUp();


        // Fade Top Panel  -->

    var target = $('.fademe');
        var targetHeight = target.outerHeight();
        $(document).scroll(function(e){
            var scrollPercent = (targetHeight - window.scrollY) / targetHeight;
            if(scrollPercent >= 0){
                target.css('opacity', scrollPercent);
            }
        }); 


      // Contact Form Send -->

      $('#submit').click(function(){
            $.post("send.php", $("#mycontactform").serialize(),  function(data) {   });
                 $('#success').html('Message sent!');
                 $('#success').hide(2000);


                    $('#name1').val('');
                    $('#telephone').val('');
                    $('#email').val('');
                    $('#message').val('');

            });


// Viberating Icons -->

      var interval = 10;
        var duration= 1000;
        var shake= 3;
        var selector = $('.viberate'); /* Your own container ID*/
        $(selector).each(function(){
            var elem = this;
            var vibrateIndex;
            var timeoutIndex;
            $(this).hover( /* The button ID */
                function(){ 
                    vibrateIndex = setInterval(function(){
                      vibrate(elem); 
                    }, interval, 0);
                    timeoutIndex = setTimeout(function(){clearInterval(vibrateIndex)},1000);
                },
                function(){
                clearInterval(vibrateIndex);
                clearTimeout(timeoutIndex); 
                }
            );
        })

            var vibrate = function(elem){
                $(elem).stop(true,false)
                .css({position: 'relative', 
                left: Math.round(Math.random() * shake) - ((shake + 1) / 2) +'px', 
                top: Math.round(Math.random() * shake) - ((shake + 1) / 2) +'px'
            });
         }


    $("#posts").masonry({
        itemSelector: '.post',
        isAnimated: true,
        columnWidth: function(containerWidth) {

        var width = $(window).width();
        var col = 300;


        if (width < 1200 && width >= 980) {
            col = 240;
            } else if (width < 980 && width >= 768) {
                col = 186;
            }

            return col;
            }
            });

    }

</script>
```

I put all JS in one **init()** function. Now after your ajax is loaded call that function.

*And check syntax I maybe lost some brackets*.

Comment: thanks for the response.. when i put the js files at the bottom of the page some of the content from the page i want to load doesnt load.. having real problems with this.. my css seems to work ok though

Comment: sorry the content works fine.. ive put the js files at the bottom in the main index page with the div i want to load the content.. but the js scripts still not working..

Comment: Probably your JS works on document load. You need to change it tou work on ajax load. For example you can put it in function and call on `ajax success`.

Comment: See updated code. it need to help, but probably you need to read about `asynchronous load`. because some scripts can brake in this case.

Comment: tried it this way.. works sometimes.. sometimes it doesnt<script>
           $.ajax({
            url: "pages/index.php",
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(html) {
                $('#st-accordion2').accordion();
            }
        });

    </script>

Comment: Sometimes? Or first time works in second load not? If you have problem in second call then you need to find async load for it. and same for every script. It probably will be headache, but I don't know any other way.

Comment: first time works ok, but when i click to go back to the page it doesnt work :S really confusing stuff this..

Comment: Check for **reinit** of accordion in documentation.